# What does install mean

Tags: xbox-360

I have Battlefield 3 and went to browse games on my Xbox 360 and clicked on it and it gave me the option of install and did not know what that meant. Does that mean I can put the game on my hard drive and forget about the disk?

Comment: Basically you will still need the disc to launch the game, but the game will load from the hard drive instead of constantly reading from the disc.